# Incude comments in search

Tags: comments, search

Is there a code snippet I can add to my functions.php, etc., that will include comments in the search (without plugin)?

Answer (score 2):

Whether you put custom code in your theme's `functions.php` or in a plugin, you're still using custom code.  So I'm going to ignore your "without a plugin" requirement and instead suggest these two plugins:

- [Search Everything](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/)
- [Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/)

There is absolutely ***no reason*** to use custom functionality in `functions.php` rather than a plugin.  When you're asking for such advanced/complex functionality as a global search, that requirement becomes a huge limitation and will prevent you from *ever* finding the answer you're looking for.

If you're still hung up on not using a plugin, you might want to offload the actual search to another engine like Google.  In that case, this [video tutorial](http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-add-google-custom-search-to-wordpress-without-any-plugin-video-tutorial-3967) on integrating a custom Google search might be useful.

Comment: Saying there's "absolutely no reason to use custom functionality in `functions.php` rather than a plugin" is too black and white. In a perfect world, where every single plugin developer uses best practices and knows what they're doing this might be true, but we don't live in that world. Code integrity is just one reason to consider doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the comments table to your search which will allow you to search the comment contents and even author names if you like.

Add this to your `functions.php` to search comment contents and author names:

```
function search_comments_join($join) {
    global $wpdb;

    if(is_search()) {
        $join .=' LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->comments.' ON '.$wpdb->posts.'.ID = '.$wpdb->comments.'.comment_post_ID ';
    }

    return $join;
}
add_filter('posts_join', 'search_comments_join');

function search_comments_where($where) {
    global $wpdb;

    if(is_search()) {
        $where = preg_replace(
            "/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
            "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->comments.".comment_author LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->comments.".comment_content LIKE $1)",
            $where
        );
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'search_comments_where');

function search_comments_distinct($where) {
    global $wpdb;

    if(is_search()) {
        return "DISTINCT";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_distinct', 'search_comments_distinct');
```

If you don't want to search comment author names just remove the `OR (".$wpdb->comments.".comment_author LIKE $1)` from the `$where` function.

Comment: This is an actual answer, compared to the most-upvoted one on this thread :O